# Android R.java missing in gen folder

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am new to Android application development. I'm using Kali linux os. When I create a sample project I receive an error message:

> R cannot be resolved to be a variable.

When I checked, there is no R.java in the gen folder. Buildconfig.java is present there. I had cleaned the project as stated in other answers. Updated sdk. But it's still not working.

It worked pretty well in other os. in backtrack older version of kali linux. But not in this

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem pefore . as i remember its because lake "Android Support Library" in Android SDK Extra , whene i install that , my probleme solve
Wish Help you

Answer (score 0):

Missing R.java is due to **Syntax Error** in **Layout Files** / **xml Files** or **ManifestFile** or **styles**, **Values** file in short in any of **xml File**
And also Newer version of ADT also needs **AndroidSupport Library**

alternatively it could be cause due to Wrongly configured **Java Build Path**

and also you must insure that all jars are check in JavaBuildPaths **order and Export** tab
[image]